# Using matplotlib and PySide6 with snake_case to display a graph results in a black canvas

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib, pyside, pyside6

I am currently trying to draw a graph with PySide6 (6.6.1) and matplotlib (3.8.2). However, this only works as intended if I don't use the snake_case feature of PySide6. If I use snake_case, only a black canvas is displayed.

```py
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from __feature__ import snake_case


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        figure = Figure()
        ax = figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1])
        canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(figure)
        self.set_central_widget(canvas)
        self.show()


app = QApplication()
w = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Is this a bug or is there a way to work around the problem?

Comment: Possibly similar to other related bugs (like [PYSIDE-1705](//bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1705), or [matplotlib-26677](//github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/26677)). I, for one, have always disliked and discouraged that feature; I find it completely unnecessary (not to mention the fact that it breaks naming style, making it inconsistent with the documentation), and since it was introduced it only created more issues than the small benefits it would eventually provide. I sincerely hope they'll remove it sooner or later. Consider reporting it, in the meantime avoid that "feature".

Answer (score 0):

**workaround**

we can add the snake case versions of the qt methods which were reimpl. in Figure class and let them call the camelCase version

```py
import re

_RE_CAMELCASE_SNAKE_CASE = re.compile(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])')

# qt methods reimpl. in Figure
_QT6_METHODS = [
    'enterEvent',
    'keyPressEvent',
    'keyReleaseEvent',
    'leaveEvent',
    'mouseDoubleClickEvent',
    'mouseMoveEvent',
    'mousePressEvent',
    'mouseReleaseEvent',
    'paintEvent',
    'resizeEvent',
    'showEvent',
    'wheelEvent',

    'sizeHint',
    'minimumSizeHint'
]

def _camel_to_snake(camel_case: str) -> str:
    """convert camelCase to snake_case"""
    return _RE_CAMELCASE_SNAKE_CASE.sub('_', camel_case).lower()

def add_snake_case_methods(cls):
    
    for method in _QT6_METHODS:
        setattr(cls, _camel_to_snake(method), getattr(cls, method))

    return cls
```

then we can use it like

```py
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

from __feature__ import snake_case

FigureCanvasQTAgg = add_snake_case_methods(FigureCanvasQTAgg)
```